# How to use context API consumer in getInitialProps Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to use the context API inside `getInitialProps` to handle the spinner display when calling requests.

How do I call my context methods inside `getInitialProps`?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible because `getInitialProps` run on server-side. Instead, you can call `useContext` on `useEffect` hook.